# Only execute method after X number of seconds since last use

Tags: c#, timer, foreach, wait

I have a foreach statement, and I need to make it so that a method called at the end of the foreach and if statements only executes after 3 seconds from it's last execution time.

Here's the code.

```
  //Go over Array for each id in allItems
  foreach (int id in allItems)
            {
                if (offered > 0 && itemsAdded != (offered * 3) && tDown)
                {
                    List<Inventory.Item> items = Trade.MyInventory.GetItemsByDefindex(id);
                    foreach (Inventory.Item item in items)
                    {
                        if (!Trade.myOfferedItems.ContainsValue(item.Id))
                        {
                            //Code to only execute if x seconds have passed since it last executed.
                            if (Trade.AddItem(item.Id))
                            {
                                itemsAdded++;
                                break;
                            }
                            //end code delay execution 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And I don't want to Sleep it, since when an item is added, I need to get confirmation from the server that the item has been added.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple time comparison?

```
var lastExecution = DateTime.Now;

if((DateTime.Now - lastExecution).TotalSeconds >= 3)
...
```

You could save 'lastExecution' in your Trade-Class. Of course, the code block is not called (items are not added) with this solution if the 3 seconds haven't elapsed.

--//---------------------------------

Different solution with a timer: we add programmatically a Windows Forms timer component. But you will end in Programmers Hell if you use this solution ;-)

```
//declare the timer
private static System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();


//adds the event and event handler (=the method that will be called)
//call this line only call once
tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

//call the following line once (unless you want to change the time)
tmr.Interval = 3000;    //sets timer to 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds

//call this line every time you need a 'timeout'
tmr.Start();            //start timer           


//called by timer
private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
  Console.WriteLine("3 seconds elapsed. disabling timer");
  tmr.Stop(); //disable timer
}
```

Comment: I need the code to execute, everytime, just not to fast. If that makes sense? I have to wait on the server to verify, accept, and send confirmation back. And I don't want it to add them to fast.

Comment: If you just need to wait for the response don't rely on time, make a [queue](http://www.dotnetperls.com/queue). Your background thread that communicates with your server sends the first 'command' and wait until it receives the answer with the next 'command' and then sends the next 'command' from the queue and so on. (I guess you do this in a background thread, as it should be with all network/i-net communication).

Answer (score 1):

```
        DateTime? lastCallDate = null;
        foreach (int id in allItems)
        {
            if (offered > 0 && itemsAdded != (offered * 3) && tDown)
            {
                List<Inventory.Item> items = Trade.MyInventory.GetItemsByDefindex(id);
                foreach (Inventory.Item item in items)
                {
                    if (!Trade.myOfferedItems.ContainsValue(item.Id))
                    {
                        //execute if 3 seconds have passed since it last execution...
                        bool wasExecuted = false;
                        while (!wasExecuted)
                        {
                            if (lastCallDate == null || lastCallDate.Value.AddSeconds(3) < DateTime.Now)
                            {
                                lastCallDate = DateTime.Now;
                                if (Trade.AddItem(item.Id))
                                {
                                    itemsAdded++;
                                    break;
                                }
                                wasExecuted = true;
                            }
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```